# IntelliJ IDEA is taking forever to compile a simple "Hello World!" code using MacBook

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello World!" code, but it seems not to be working. I uninstalled the anti-virus "ESET Cybersecurity Pro" on my computer, and it still didn't help. It is really an issue for me to run my codes.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable or configure ESET to [not block localhost connections](https://forum.eset.com/topic/22080-mac-firewall-issue-after-update-to-684000) and ignore IDE/project folders. Contact ESET support for more details.

Comment: Thank you @CrazyCoder I totally uninstalled both IntelliJ and ESET then reinstalled them back and it works now. Thanks!